# how to integrate Angular application with Springboot app for the email sending functionality

Tags: angular, spring-boot

need some help on how we can get the springboot application integrated into the Angular project. To give a background, i have created a static website using angular, and i have another simpler project springboot email client sending application, which sends email to gmail account. So now, what i would like to do is, get the springboot email client application functionality into the Angular project, wherein i have a form which will send out the user data when the user click on send button. I am quite new to angular and springboot, so for learning purpose i created two different projects and now i would like use the email service in the angular project(in the form send functionality). I am not quite sure if this two projects can be clubbed into one and if yes, can we anyone guide me on how to go about doing it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p02bB.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiX0e.png)

Comment: I have added the Angular project screenshot and the Springboot project screenshot for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't integrate you Spring Boot app into Angular, you integrate your builded Angular app into the Spring boot one when you want to deploy your application.

**In production :**
When you build your Angular app (using `ng build --configuration production`), you will get some nbasic web ressources like HTML files, CSS files, JS files etc... You need a webserver to serve those files to your clients. Your Spring Boot app can do this, you just need to put those files into your src/main/resources/static file (there are other path that can do the same).

**In development :**
You want to keep the dev server (`ng serve` with Angular CLI) and your Spring Boot app at the same time as hot reloading is a must. So, you need to tell Angular CLI to redirect all request to your API (ex: `/api`) to your Spring Boot app which is listening to another port. To do this, [you need ton configure it](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server).

Comment: Thanks for the details, can it be any other simpler way, coz i just have one form (only 5 fields) and that form details needs to be sent over to gmail email account.

Comment: It can't be simpler using Angular. If you only have 5 fields, you could also use JSP instead of Angular : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp